# LinqToXml remove element confusion

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file something like the one below. I'm just trying to remove one element, but I think I am missing out on something. I am getting this error:

> 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for 'First'
>   and no extension method 'First' accepting a first

```
XElement document=XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("data.xml"));
var x = from veri in document.Elements("Book") 
where veri.Attribute("ID").Value == "5" select veri.First();         
x.Remove();


<Books>
<Book ID="1">
<name>asp.net</name>
<author>selim</author>
<page>300</page>
 </Book>


 </Books>
```

Comment: Have you added the `System.Linq` namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the top of your C# file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Yes I have added Linq namesapce

Comment: There is something strange .After close solution and reopen than build project  visual studio says succeed but i cant do it more than one time if i try to build second time then i get this message again .I have tried five times this  .And every time same result .İs it normal?